# php check if a process is running with arg

Tags: php, shell

i got this code going

```
exec("/usr/bin/php cron3.php 1", $output, $return);
if ($return == 0) {
    echo "Ok, process is running\n";
}
```

It will echo ok for all cron3.php, but I wanna it check the arg also which in this case is 1

if i type something like

```
exec("/usr/bin/php cron3.php z", $output, $return);
if ($return == 0) {
    echo "Ok, process is running\n";
}

 7929 pts/1    S      0:00 /usr/bin/php cron3.php 8
 8248 pts/1    S      0:00 /usr/bin/php cron3.php 0
 8296 pts/1    S      0:00 /usr/bin/php cron3.php 1
 8432 pts/1    S      0:00 /usr/bin/php cron3.php 3
```

If z is not send in as arg at the process, it should not return ok (which now it does return ok)

How do I change my code to get it working with arg check.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By globally using the `$argv` variable or `$_SERVER['argv']` elsewhere, you should be able to read all arguments. The arguments will be available as an array.

Note that the first value in the array is the file you are executing.
From your example, your `$argv` variable will look like this:

```
$argv[0] = "cron3.php"
$argv[1] = "z"
```

Comment: this is not what he is asking

Comment: To me it sounds like he needs a way to check the arguments from inside cron3.php, right? Or it sounds like he wants to change the code he has written here, but the argument check has to happen inside the file that is going to be executed. I therefore provided the information he needs to change his code so it might return not ok when he wants to. @Dagon

Comment: No worries. Would appreciate i you removed your thumb down (if that was you) if you know think it's an appropiate answer :D @Dagon

Comment: doh messed up the clicking, if you edit it i can, sorry! ;-)

Comment: Done, and tyty @Dagon

Comment: You do not have a script to tell if a process is running from before? The code you have provided in your question, isn't that real data? Or is that how you feel it will look like in the end when you have manage to complete your cron3.php file? @Max